# Returning a different object than input on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

This is more of a proof of concept than anything else. I have a model for "Costumes." Each costume has data associated with it including an identifier named `cid`. Note that this is unrelated to the `id` that rails automatically creates.

The idea is that if someone tries to create a costume with a `cid` that is in use, they will get back the costume that already has that `cid`. The use case is that if the only field they fill out is `cid`, rails can get the rest.

Note that I do not want to call another method in the controller. I want this to happen when I hit create on the new costume form.

I would like to use a `before_save` callback to accomplish this along with something like `find_or_initialize_by`

```
class Costume < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :get_costumes

  def get_costumes
    Costume.find_or_initialize_by(cid: self.cid)
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you do this.

```
 def self.get_costume(cid) // notice singularity 
   Costume.find_or_create_by_cid(cid)
 end
```

in any controller like customs_controller.rb

```
  Costume.get_costume(122)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get a NameError when I prepend `self` to the method name or use the singularity. My goal is that when someone clicks `create` the show page shows them the costume with the given cid. This is a trivial example that will be used in another form later.

Comment: shouldn't it be: `def self.get_costume(cid) Costume.find_or_create_by_cid(cid) end`?